# Section numbering with chapter in amsbook

Tags: sectioning, numbering, chapters, amsbook

I'm using `amsbook` to write a report. I'm using `\chapter{}`s and `\section{}`s, and their numbering is fine.
However, `\section{}`s are numbered sequentially inside each `\chapter{}`, but without the indication of the `\chapter{}`: basically, I'm getting `Section 1` instead of `1.1`, and similarly `Subsection 1` instead of `1.1.1`.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 26):

Write the following in the preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
```

Comment: Instead of posting a “Thank you” as a comment, you should thank by upvoting the answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark).

Answer (score 13):

alternate approach:  in the preamble,

```
\numberwithin{section}{chapter}
```

but it doesn't carry along to subsections; for that you'd need

```
\numberwithin{subsection}{section}
```

etc.