# amsbook theorem numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems, amsbook

I want theorems to be labeled of the form Part.Chapter.Section.number so I tried

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{part}.\thechapter.\arabic{section}} 
\newtheorem{book}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{AddProp}[book]{Additive Property of Equality}
\begin{AddProp} Testing \end{AddProp}
```

But does what I want, but as a side effect it also changes the sections, is there a way to only change the theorem numbering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To have your `AddProp` "theorem" numbered by section using Part.Chapter.Section.Number, you can use:

```
\newtheorem{book}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{AddProp}[book]{Additive Property of Equality}
\renewcommand{\thebook}{\thepart.\thesection.\arabic{book}}
```

This will also reset your `book` counter after every new `\section`. Here's a minimal example showing the usage/output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\newtheorem{book}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{AddProp}[book]{Additive Property of Equality}
\renewcommand{\thebook}{\thepart.\thesection.\arabic{book}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{part}{3} \part{A part}
\setcounter{chapter}{4} \chapter{A chapter}
\setcounter{section}{12} \section{A section}
\begin{AddProp} Testing \end{AddProp}
\section{Another section}
\begin{AddProp} Testing \end{AddProp}
\end{document}​
```

---

If you wish to maintain this structure, but have the `book` counter only reset every `\chapter`, then you need to drop the `[section]` part from the definition of the `book` theorem, and add the counter reset to your `book` counter manually:

```
%...
\newtheorem{book}{Theorem}%[section]
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{book}{chapter}\makeatother
%...
```

This functionality is provided by the [`chngcntr` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) as well as [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) via user-friendly macros. Since you're using `amsbook`, you could use `\numberwithin{book}{chapter}`. See [Master and slave counters](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-addtoreset) and perhaps [Section numbering with chapter in `amsbook`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20837/5764).