# Indent problem in list of tables (and figures) captions

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, amsbook

I am using amsbook document class and the list of tables and figures is has a very small indent (from the left) and collides with the chapter and table/figure numbering. I cannot use tocloft package because it is incompatible with amsbook. I have found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297277/111537) answer but it does not have quite what I want. (The dotted line is good however, didn't have that before). Is there any way to indent the captions a little bit more to the right?

Here is a MWE of my current situation:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

% Editing the toc page with amsbook document class
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297277/111537
 \usepackage{etoolbox}

% 'Table of contents' instead of 'Contents'
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
% Use the next line if you want capital letters
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of contents}}

% Uppercase 'CHAPTER' label in toc
\patchcmd{\tocchapter}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}

% Leader dots in toc
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2em} % <-- depending on the total number of pages
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\,.\,}\hfil}
  {}{}
\makeatother




%  ************  begin my definitions  *******************

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20837/section-numbering-with-chapter-in-amsbook
% show chapter numbers in sections!

% do the same for tables and figures:
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{table}}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Seminorms and the Minkowski functional}

\chapter{Convex polytopes}
\section{Convex}
\section{Polytopes}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The numbers don't overlap in this example but you can see the last two have very little space between them. I would like to add at 3-4 characters extra spacing between them.

[image: Not enough spacing listoftables]

Comment: Add \def\l@table{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{2.4em}{}} inside the \madeatletter ... \makeatother.  The 2,4em was originally 1.5pc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That fixed it!! Thanks! If you want to write it as an answer and I ll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TOC has an elaborate system to measure how much space is needed, but the list of tables and figures were simply assigned widths of 1.5pc (originally).

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

% Editing the toc page with amsbook document class
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297277/111537
 \usepackage{etoolbox}

% 'Table of contents' instead of 'Contents'
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
% Use the next line if you want capital letters
%\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase{Table of contents}}

% Uppercase 'CHAPTER' label in toc
\patchcmd{\tocchapter}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}

% Leader dots in toc
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2em} % <-- depending on the total number of pages
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\leaders\hbox{\,.\,}\hfil}
  {}{}

\def\l@table{\@tocline{0}{3pt plus2pt}{0pt}{2.4em}{}}
\let\l@figure=\l@table
\makeatother

%  ************  begin my definitions  *******************

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20837/section-numbering-with-chapter-in-amsbook
% show chapter numbers in sections!

% do the same for tables and figures:
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thechapter.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter.\arabic{table}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\chapter{Seminorms and the Minkowski functional}

\chapter{Convex polytopes}
\section{Convex}
\section{Polytopes}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\caption{Table1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```