# Aligning Multi-line Caption in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, align

I have modified my list of figures so that it includes Fig. figure number before each caption in List of Figures.  This done by using the following code.

```
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoftables%
}
```

However, I am not able to align figure caption which extends to second line. What should be done to align the multi-line figure caption in list of figures.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: You would have better luck modifying \l@figure and \l@table, which set the indentation,

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326573/indent-problem-in-list-of-tables-and-figures-captions (although it has other modifications you may not need).

Comment: I tried the suggestion in above comment. However its showing following error   ! Undefined control sequence.
\l@figure ->\@tocline

Comment: The first step is finding the current definition of \l@figure, which usually depends on the document class.  \meaning\l@figure would belp.  (don't forget \makeatletter ... \makeatother)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get alignment using this code

```
\contentsmargin{1cm}
\titlecontents{figure}
  [2.5cm]
  {}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \makebox[2.5cm][l]{Figure~\thecontentslabel}%
    }%
  }
  {\hspace{-2.5cm}}
  {\titlerule*[6pt]{}\contentspage}
```

However, in some cases the page number comes down